# callback functions - url redirection

Tags: json, callback, jquery-callback

I want to create a callback function, which handles some javasripting - this callback function  if I want to append to a redirection url - how do I do that - I am confused where to start - especially callback functions -

Answer (score 1):

callback are some code called on an event,

events can be click, mousemove, keypress, window resize, ...

you can start search google about event handling in js

by example http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

you can use some js library too, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) who help you managing event

for the url redirection, have a look at *location.href*

```
location.href = "http://google.com";
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, my question is how do i add it to a url and how does that url used for redirection upon some event say button click will b calling this callback function which has some js in it.

Comment: add a callback to a url mean just nothing, please clarify your question
you want add a callback on a <a href link click ?